# Create Multiplatform docker image without pushing each image with separate tag

Tags: docker, docker-registry, dockerhub

I tried to create a Multiplatform docker image using this docker blog post https://www.docker.com/blog/multi-platform-docker-builds/

And it worked fine but as a result I got several images (eg. Multiplatform with tag:latest, and one for each platform - :amd64, :arm64 etc.)

But for example in ubuntu official registry (https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu) they have only one Multiplatform image with tag :latest and no other images.

How did they do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out how to do it. I need to make my image Official Docker Image

https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/official_images/